# Clipping a polygon based on feature from overlapping polygon QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am working in QGIS
I have two overlapping polygon layers:

1. A species distribution polygon named `species_dist`
2. A bathymetry polygon named `depth`

The bathymetry polygon attribute table has a depth field with values from 1 to 19.

I want to clip `species_dist` to only keep the area that overlaps with depth values 1 to 3 of `depth`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select by attribute` or `select by expression` everything on the bathymetry layer with the desired values, then clip the species with this selection.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that has solved my problem. I am running into issues to filter by attribute however. I can only filter by running the following filter command:  "depth"  = 1 OR  "depth" = 2 OR  "depth" =3 and if i try "depth" = 1 OR 2 OR 3 it does not work. but that is another issue i guess.

Comment: @ninafb `depth IN ('1','2','3')` should work.